# Find theta notation of the following while loop

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have the homework question:

> 1. Find a theta notation for the number of times the statement x = x + 1 is executed. (10 points).

```
i = n
while (i >= 1)
{
   for j = 1 to n
   {
      x = x + 1
   }
   i = i/2
}
```

### This is what I have done:

Ok first let’s make it easier. We will fist find the order of growth of:

```
while (i >= 1)
{
   x = x + 1
   i = i/2
}
```

that has order of growth `O(log(n))`  actually log base 2

the other inner for loop will execute n times therefore the algorithm should be of order:

`O(log(n)*n)`

---

The part where I get confused is that I am supposed to find theta notation NOT big-O. I know that theta notation is suppose to bound the function on the upper and lower limit. Will the correct answer be `Theta(log(n)*n)`?

I have found the answer in this [link](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100203122230AAP41TQ) but I don't know how you get to that answer. Why they claim that the answer is Theta(n) ?

Comment: I'm hungry for tortoises now, if only I could catch one.

Comment: It should be `theta(log(n)*n)`

Comment: I think that too so the link http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100203122230AAP41TQ is wrong then?

Comment: (a)  Differentiate  between  the  big  O  notation  and  big O  notation.  Find  time  complexity  of  the  following functions in  theta-notation :
(i)  f(n) :  n^3 +  2^1000
(ii) f(n) :n^4+!n+100
(iii) f(n) :n^3+  n^2log n+log4^ n+  20
(iv)  f(n) :  2^n  +  !n  log n  +  log(log(log(n))) +  100  :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should now prove it is also `Omega(nlogn)`.

I won't show exactly how, since it is homework - but it is with the same principles you show `O(nlogn)`.  You need to show [unformally explnation:] that the **asymptotic behavior** of the function, is growing **at least as fast** as `nlogn`. [for big O you show it is growing at most at the rate of `nlogn`].

Remember that if a function is both `O(nlogn)` and `Omega(nlogn)`, it is Theta(nlogn) [and vise versa]

**p.s.** Your hunch is true, it is easy to show it is not `Omega(n)`, and thus it is not `Theta(n)`

**p.s. 2**: I think the author of the other answer confused with a different program:

```
i = n
while (i >= 1)
{
   for j = 1 to i //NOTE: i instead of N here!
   {
      x = x + 1
   }
   i = i/2
}
```

The above program is indeed `Theta(n)`, but it is different from the one you have provided.

Comment: I should had removed the homework tag lol. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So in other words I am missing the other asymtop the lower one right? that is the one you called Omega. so I can just pick a function that grows very slowly and that will technically be correct? anyways let's say that I find Omega(nlogn). so then my final answer will have to include big-O and Omega?

Comment: @TonoNam: If you prove that your algorithm lower complexity bound if `Omega(f(n))`, and its upper complexity bound is `O(f(n))`, then its complexity is `Theta(f(n))`. [and vise versa]. Of course it is also correct for `f(n)=nlogn`, so if you prove `Omega(nlogn)` and `O(nlogn)`, you actually proved `Theta(nlogn)`

Comment: @TonoNam: Also look at my second edit, I think I know why the answerer of the other question claimed it to be `Theta(n)`, he probably confused with a different similar algorithm.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. that's why it did not make sense. Anyways I will post an answer based on your explanation. take a look at it. I appreciate very much your help!

Answer (score 2):

Rephrasing your code fragment in a more formal way, so that it could be represented easily using Sigma Notation:

```
for (i = n; i >= 1; i = i/2 ) {
    for j = 1; j <= n; j ++) {
        x = x + 1; // instruction of cost 'c'
    }
}
```

We obtain:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! If we would have a code in the form:
     for (i=0; i <=3n^3; i=i+3) { 
         for (j=i; j<= 3n; j=j+3 ) {  
              x=x+1; 
          } 
     } 
  could we also use Sigma Notation?

Comment: I mean in my case the step grows by adding something, but in your case the step gets smaller by dividing something at the first for.

Answer (score 0):

As [@amit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572670/amit) mentions I already have the upper limit of the function and that is Big-O which it actually is O(n*lgn). if I plot a table of that function I will get something like:

```
n   n*lng
1   0
2   2
3   4.754887502
4   8
5   11.60964047
6   15.509775
7   19.65148445
8   24
9   28.52932501
10  33.21928095
```

because that is big-O then that means that the real function will be bounded by those values. In other words the real values should be less than the values at the table. for example taking a point for instace when `n=9` we know that the answer should be less than or equal to `28.52932501` by looking at the table

So now we are missing to find Omega and that is the other bound. I think that the lower bound function should be  `Omega(n)`  and then we will get the table

```
n   Omega(n)
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
.......
```

so that will be the other bound. If we take again point for example where `n = 9` again then that will give us 9. that means that our real function should give us a value greater or equal to 9. based on our big-O function we also know that it should be les than or equal to `28.52932501`