# Time complexity of the following algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm learning Big-O notation right now and stumbled across this small algorithm in another thread:

```
i = n
while (i >= 1)
{
    for j = 1 to i  // NOTE: i instead of n here!
    {
      x = x + 1
    }
    i = i/2
}
```

According to the author of the post, the complexity is Θ(n), but I can't figure out how. I think the while loop's complexity is Θ(log(n)). The for loop's complexity from what I was thinking would also be Θ(log(n)) because the number of iterations would be halved each time.

So, wouldn't the complexity of the whole thing be Θ(log(n) * log(n)), or am I doing something wrong?

Edit: the segment is in the best answer of this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556782/find-theta-notation-of-the-following-while-loop#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556782/find-theta-notation-of-the-following-while-loop#_=_)

Comment: You should link to the question you saw before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine for simplicity that `n = 2^k`. How many times `x` gets incremented? It easily follows this is [Geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

> 2^k + 2^(k - 1) + 2^(k - 2) + ... + 1 = 2^(k + 1) - 1 = 2 * n - 1

So this part is `Θ(n)`. Also `i` get's halved `k = log n` times and it has no asymptotic effect to `Θ(n)`.

Comment: In case someone wants to study up on this sort of thing, this is called a geometric series.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `i` for each iteration of the `while` loop, which is also how many iterations the `for` loop has, are n, n/2, n/4, ..., and the overall complexity is the sum of those.  That puts it at roughly 2n, which gets you your Theta(n).